# Creating file in Utf-8 encoding results to strange characters

Tags: sql-server, encoding, utf-8, bcp

I am writing the results of my stored procedures to an Xml file using the Utf-8 encoding. The Xml data, as seen on *Sql Server Management Studio* and `Notepad` look normal. But when I open my file with Utf-8 encoding on *Notepad++* or *Visual Studio Code* I see that all `ä`, `ö` and `å` characters become unrecognized.

```
SET @sqlCommand =
     'bcp "EXEC '  +@db + '.dbo.GetXmlDataKund" queryout "' + @filePath + @fileName + ' "  -T   -c -C65001 -C'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sqlCommand
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly does *"become unrecognized"* look like?

Comment: @deceze like `xC4` in *Notepad++* and `�` in *VS Code*.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL Server version probably doesn't support UTF-8. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).

The essence: "Versions prior to version 13 (SQL Server 2016) do not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding). Versions beginning with 13 can import UTF-8 encoding to earlier versions of SQL Server."

If you have SQL Server 2014 SP 2, you can use [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3136780/utf-8-encoding-support-for-the-bcp-utility-and-bulk-insert-transact-sql-command-in-sql-server-2014-sp2) update to add support for UTF-8.

To use UTF-16 instead, you should add the `-w` parameter.

Comment: Do you think changing to `UTF-16` will solve the problem?

Comment: I would expect so, yeah. Your file will be bigger than with UTF-8, though, but I doubt it will be a problem.

Comment: I will try and come back to you on this.